# how can i use location which is found in another class?

Tags: xcode, class, null, location, nslog

i am taking user's location with this code:

```
@implementation TabBar
CLLocationManager *locationManager;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    // NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        UsersCurrentLongitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        UsersCurrentLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

        NSLog(@"Latitude:%@,Longitude:%@",UsersCurrentLatitude,UsersCurrentLongitude);

    }
```

and in nslog screen it is showing location successfully. but when i want to use that locations in another class which imported my location class (in this case it is TabBar), location turns null. what can i do to solve this issue?
Edited:

After I try two different method for my issue i am still getting null at NsLog:

First Method:

At AppDelegate.h:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *latitude;
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString 
At AppDelegate.mlongitude;
@synthesize latitude;
@synthesize longitude;
```

At TabBar.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setLatitude:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]];

        [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setLongitude:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]];
}  
    }

At my SecondView.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"
(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *UsersCurrentLatitude = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] latitude];
    NSString *UsersCurrentLongitude = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] longitude];

NSLog(@"latitude:%@,longitude%@",UsersCurrentLatitude,UsersCurrentLongitude);
}
```

Second Method (I found a tutorial in youtube and arrange that method for my issue, so it can be meaningless code):

I made a NSObject Class which is named SingletonClass
At SingletonClass.h

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface SingletonClass : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *UsersCurrentLatitude;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *UsersCurrentLongitude;

+(SingletonClass *) Lokasyon;

@end
```

At SingletonClass.m

```
#import "SingletonClass.h"

@implementation SingletonClass {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;

}
@synthesize UsersCurrentLongitude;
@synthesize UsersCurrentLatitude;

+(SingletonClass *)Lokasyon {
    static SingletonClass *Lokasyon = nil;
    if (!Lokasyon) {
        Lokasyon = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init];
        }
    return Lokasyon;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
      UsersCurrentLongitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        UsersCurrentLatitude = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

    }
}
@end
```

At my SeconViewController

```
#import "SingletonClass.h"
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

NSNumber *UsersCurrentLongitude1 = [[SingletonClass Lokasyon]UsersCurrentLongitude];
    NSLog(@"%@",UsersCurrentLongitude1);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare them in the `Appdelegate.h` like-

```
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *latitude;
    @property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *longitude;
```

make sure u, synthesize `latitude` and `longitude` properties in `AppDelegate.m` class.

Set them in `TabBar.m` where u get the location in `CLLocationManager`'s `didUpdateToLocation:`

```
if (currentLocation != nil) {
    [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setLatitude:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude]];

    [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setLongitude:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude]];

        //UsersCurrentLatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];

        //NSLog(@"Latitude:%@,Longitude:%@",UsersCurrentLatitude,UsersCurrentLongitude);

    }
```

Access in other class(es) like-

```
    NSString aLatitude = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] latitude];
    NSString aLongitude = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] longitude];
```

PS: there are many other ways to do what u need, like- Having a `Singleton` class or Saving in the iOS app `File system` i.e. in App `Sandbox`..

Comment: nslog is still showing null. i will try Singleton way which you mentioned. thank you anyway

Comment: using an Entire `Singleton` Class just to save two `Strings` is **not** a good idea!

Comment: ok, so i have to use first method but i am still getting null at NsLog. do you see any error in first method's code? actually i can get user's location at every view controller separately but i thought that will make difficulty in terms of memory of application.

Comment: ok it turns out a consistent situation. if i do specific things at iphone simulator it gives me locations at NsLog. but if i go with a different path at simulator it gives me null at NsLog.

Comment: i solve that issue with calling that method with a delay. thank you.